# JavaFX TextField ошибка NullPointerException

Tags: javafx

Пытаюсь написать небольшое приложение, которое отображает в таблице список сотрудников и при нажатии на колонку с сотрудником открывает новое окно для его редактирования. В новом окне есть 4 поля `textField` и кнопка, в поля я устанавливаю текст, при установке текста я получаю `NullPointerException`, помогите разобраться в чем проблема. Спасибо.

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

    stage.setTitle("Employees List");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

```
public class EmployeeController {

private ObservableList<Employee> employeeData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private static ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

@FXML
private TableView<Employee> tableEmployees;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, Long> idColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, Long> originalidColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, String> aliasColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, String> nameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, String> firstNameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, String> secondNameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, String> lastNameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, Date> createDateColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, String> refinedColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, Long> sortNoColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, Short> hiddenColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, String> passwordColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Employee, String> saltColumn;

// инициализируем форму данными
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    initData();

    // устанавливаем тип и значение которое должно хранится в колонке
    idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
    originalidColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("originalid"));
    aliasColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("alias"));
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
    secondNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("secondName"));
    lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
    createDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("createDate"));
    refinedColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("refined"));
    sortNoColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("sortNo"));
    hiddenColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("hidden"));
    passwordColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("password"));
    saltColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("salt"));

    // заполняем таблицу данными
    tableEmployees.setItems(employeeData);

    tableEmployees.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<Employee> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (!row.isEmpty() && event.getButton()==MouseButton.PRIMARY && event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                Employee employee = row.getItem();
                EmployeeEditDialog emb = new EmployeeEditDialog();
                emb.showDialog();
                emb.setEmployee(employee);
            }
        });
        return row ;
    });
}

private void initData() {
    employeeData.addAll(getTestEmployeesList());
}

public static ArrayList<Employee> getTestEmployeesList(){

    for (long i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        employees.add(new Employee(i, null, "alias", "name", "firstName", "secondName", "lastName", new Date(), "refined", null, null, "password", "salt"));
    }
    return employees;
}
```

}

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="682.0" prefWidth="1320.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.it.ittest.jfx.controller.EmployeeController">
<TableView fx:id="tableEmployees" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="62.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1300.0">
    <columns>
        <!-- Колонки таблицы -->
        <TableColumn fx:id="idColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="id" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="originalidColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="originalid" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="aliasColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="alias" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="name" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="firstName" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="secondNameColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="secondName" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="lastNameColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="lastName" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="createDateColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="createDate" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="refinedColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="refined" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="sortNoColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="sortNo" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="hiddenColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="hidden" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="passwordColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="password" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="saltColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="salt" />
    </columns>
</TableView>
<Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="18.0" text="List all Employees:">
    <font>
        <Font name="Verdana" size="18.0" />
    </font>
</Label>
```

```
public class EmployeeEditDialog {

@FXML
private TextField nameTextField;
@FXML
private TextField firstNameTextField;
@FXML
private TextField secondNameTextField;
@FXML
private TextField lastNameTextField;

private Stage dialogStage;

private Employee employee;

@FXML
private void initialize() {

}

public void showDialog(){
    try {
        dialogStage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/EditEmployee.fxml"));
        AnchorPane anchorPane = loader.load();

        dialogStage.setTitle("Edit Employee");
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
        dialogStage.setScene(scene);
        dialogStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee){
    this.employee = employee;

    if (employee != null) {
        nameTextField.setPromptText(employee.getName());
        firstNameTextField.setPromptText(employee.getFirstName());
        secondNameTextField.setPromptText(employee.getSecondName());
        lastNameTextField.setPromptText(employee.getLastName());
    }
}

@FXML
private void updateEmployee() {
     employee.setName(nameTextField.getText());
     employee.setFirstName(firstNameTextField.getText());
     employee.setSecondName(secondNameTextField.getText());
     employee.setLastName(lastNameTextField.getText());

     dialogStage.close();
}
```

}

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPaneEdit" prefHeight="307.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.it.ittest.jfx.controller.EmployeeEditDialog">
<TextField layoutX="110.0" layoutY="30.0" fx:id="nameTextField" />
<TextField layoutX="110.0" layoutY="79.0" fx:id="firstNameTextField" />
<TextField layoutX="110.0" layoutY="130.0" fx:id="secondNameTextField" />
<TextField layoutX="110.0" layoutY="179.0" fx:id="lastNameTextField" />

<Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="33.0" text="Name">
    <font>
      <Font size="14.0"/>
    </font>
</Label>
<Label layoutX="9.0" layoutY="83.0" text="First Name">
    <font>
      <Font size="14.0"/>
    </font>
</Label>
<Label layoutX="8.0" layoutY="134.0" text="Second Name">
    <font>
      <Font size="14.0"/>
    </font>
</Label>
<Label layoutX="9.0" layoutY="183.0" text="Last Name">
    <font>
      <Font size="14.0"/>
    </font>
</Label>
<Button layoutX="97.0" layoutY="239.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#updateEmployee" text="Обновить">
    <font>
      <Font size="12.0"/>
    </font>
</Button>
```

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.it.ittest.jfx.controller.EmployeeEditDialog.setEmployee(EmployeeEditDialog.java:54)
at com.it.ittest.jfx.controller.EmployeeController.lambda$null$0(EmployeeController.java:81)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Сложно разобрать не видя структуру проекта, судя по ошибке, вы не вызвали FXMLoader.load() который инжектит в анотации @FXML поля из разметки. Если эта строчка EmployeeEditDialog emb = new EmployeeEditDialog(); это ваше новое окно, то вы его не правильно создаете.

Comment: EmployeeEditDialog это новое окно, как правельно я должен вызвать FXMLoader.load()?

Comment: Аналогично той операции что у вас в showDialog. Если у вас единомоментно предполагается только одно использование этого второго окна, то выгоднее проделать это где-то в стороне, а когда надо открывать его, забирать экземплят оттуда и устанавливать свои значения. Вызывать каждый раз fxmlloader.load() не есть правильно - это долгая операция.